# How to set an ImageIcon to a JButton and resize the picture according to the button's size?

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I've been wondering how can I set an `ImageIcon` to a button using the `Image` path and set it to a `JButton`?

I can resize the image's size according to the buttons size:

```
frontViewImageFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
MainFrame.btnFrontView.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
    frontViewImageFile).getScaledInstance(150, 150, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

But the image came from a file chooser and I can use `getScaledInstance` method to resize the picture.

How can i do this with image path since method `getScaledInstance` is undefined for the type `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageIcon icon = ...;
JButton b = ...;
Image im = icon.getImage();
Image im2 = im.getScaledInstance(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), ...);
b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(im2));
```